Idea on Bluetooth device
So, I am new to looking into patenting an idea that includes Bluetooth and an app for a device. Not new to patents in general my family holds quite a few in the waste/recycling industry. So what I want to know is if it's a new device and there isn't anything like it on the market, how or should I go about protecting my idea and invention? I want to be able to discuss my idea with confidence that it won't be stolen or something like that. Also, since it's a 2 part Bluetooth and app, would trademark and patent apply? I know a NDA offers some protection but I have also seen NDA be picked apart and not always protect the party trying to bring something to market. So my advice also is who would be a good company to talk to about developing a Bluetooth device with an app, something similar to a range extender, but not still; there will be a main device with other piggybacking off that main device and then an app to manage it all. Thanks so much in advance for any help.

Note that “there isn’t anything like it on the market” doesn’t mean anything regarding patentability.

Please try to limit your question to a single question.


how or should I go about protecting my idea and invention?

Find a patent practitioner, get their advice on patentability, and if appropriate apply for a patent.

I want to be able to discuss my idea with confidence that it won't be stolen or something like that.

Once you have at least a provisional patent application in, you probably can.

Also, since it's a 2 part Bluetooth and app, would trademark and patent apply?

Trademark protection is completely independent of patent protection, and has nothing to do with whether the product is monolithic or in parts.

I know a NDA offers some protection [...]

An NDA offers next to no protection for raw ideas. If someone you have signed an NDA with shares your idea with a third party, you will need a lot of cooperation from the culprits to prove it. Additionally most sources of funding will refuse to sign NDAs because there are always plenty of other founders around who are willing to discuss their ideas without an NDA.
